# Graphic display for new Freenas build

Tags: freenas

I've almost completed my 1st NAS server build.

I bought a silverstone 380-B 8 bay ATX case to mount an old m/b I have from an upgrade on my PC.

Gigabyte Z87X UD5H with an Intel i7-4790K cpu, 32 Gb of DDR3 corsair & 10 Sata ports.

I've fitted a Corsair LE 200 SSD for the Cache & put a 16Gb USB 3.0 for the Freenas OS.

4 x 4TB WD Red HDD's for storage.

To run a basic display monitor how do I get a cheap reliable Graphics card to attach the monitor (just to get the IP address).

I'm using Windows 10 on my PC with a Z170X-UD5 TH, 32GB Ram & i7-6700K cpu.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU you listed for the build should have a built-in GPU.  If the motherboard supports it, it should work out of the box with FreeNAS.

If that isn't an option though, just look for a cheap GPU on Amazon that supports whatever interconnect you have available, and check if it works with FreeBSD.  The NVIDIA GeForce 210 works pretty well if you just need something to get a text console (it's cheap, reliable, energy efficient, and supported almost universally by modern operating systems).  Just about anything that provides a basic VBE interface to the OS (which is almost every GPU you can find these days) should work though.